# null pointer exception when adding an object to an arraylist

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a null pointer exception with the following code where I am trying to add a object referenced by "newColumn" to an ArrayList referenced by "this.neighborColumns" in Java. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
    for (int column = xInitial; column < xFinal; ++column)
    {
        for (int row = yInitial; row < yFinal; ++row)
        {
            // TODO: To make inhibition a circle around input column, change
            // to remove conners of this rectangle inhibition
            Column newColumn = this.region.getColumn(column, row);
            if (newColumn != null)
            {
                this.neighborColumns.add(newColumn);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where to you instantiate the `neighborColumn` object? In a constructor or somewhere else?

Comment: Post your stacktrace, but at a guess neighbourColumns is null.

Comment: Please post your stacktrace and the relevant parts of the code, e.g. how does `this.neighborColumns` behave. Did you try a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code not showing how you have defined `this.neighborColumns` list, but as per your question heading I am guessing `this.neighborColumns` pointing to null;

assign neighborColums to list implementation object before performing any operation on it. Example:

```
neighborColumns = new ArrayList<type>();
```

Answer (score 1):

you might have not initialized your arraylist `neighborColumns`.

you have to initialize it before you call add on it

```
List<Type> neighborColumns = new ArrayList<>();
```

its better to check if arrayList is null before you add things into it

```
 if (newColumn != null && neighborColumns !=NULL)
            {
                this.neighborColumns.add(newColumn);
            }
```